# how to gather and analyze google map real estate search results

Tags: web-services, google-maps

Is there a google api can return real estate data from google maps? Eg. A "San Diego" search on maps.google.com with real estate option shows properties on sale or for rent. How do I gather and manipulate the results? such as sort listings by "Posted On" date? Convert the search result to RSS feed so when there is new listing I gets notificed.

The Google Maps API Web Services does not seem to offer this. The Base data api has been deprecated and real estate API seems not supported anymore.

Essentially, i want to query "San Diego, houses for sales, posted 1/01/11 and less than 200000" on google maps and get the results in XML/json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google real estate search is no more!
http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2011/01/retiring-real-estate-on-google-maps.html

Comment: too bad.. finding properties won't be as easy as before..